# I have a hover issue. When I hover the cart, cart details shows up but when I move my mouse over the cart details it goes away

Tags: hover, cart, partial

When I hover the cart, cart details shows up but when I move my mouse over the cart details it goes away. I couldnt figure it out . thanks for your helps.
 Please check my code below. When I hover .yheader-middle-menu-cart a tag, there is a div with .cart-hover class carrying my cart that I want it to show up.
This is my view code

```
<div class="yheader-middle-menu-cart">
                    <div class="ycart">
                        <a href="#" style="font-size:large">
                            @Html.Action("ItemInCart", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
                        <div class="cart-hover">
                            @Html.Action("CartHover", "Home")
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and this is my css code

```
 .yheader-middle-menu-cart a:hover + .cart-hover {
            display: block;
            -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 400ms;
            -moz-animation: fadeInUp 400ms;
            -ms-animation: fadeInUp 400ms;
            -o-animation: fadeInUp 400ms;
            animation: fadeInUp 400ms;
        }
.cart-hover {
      display: none;
      position: relative;
      top:-5px;
      left: -235px;
      background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 350px;
      display: none;
      z-index: 999;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it changing hover from a to div.